# Выравнивание разных текстов в одном блоке

Tags: html, css

Хочу сделать так, чтобы в одном блоке один текст всегда был ровно в центре блока, а второй текст был всегда справа. Сейчас пока у меня первый текст центрируется в зависимости от размера второго текста. Для понимания выделил середину

```css
.my_class {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, green 50%, red 50%);
}

.my_class a span {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container my_class">
  <a>TEXT <span>text text blah blah blah blah</span></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам придется сделать два блока, один над другим. У одного текст по центру, у второго - справа.